# Mysql nested query scope

Tags: mysql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I'm having trouble passing the reference from the external query to the secondary one. i know mysql doesn't allow you to "see" a variable reference in queries deeper than 1, but i'm not finding workaround.

```
select f.id as field_id, 
(select count(*) from field_gro fg where fg.field_id = f.id) as field_gro_count,
(select GROUP_CONCAT(id separator ',' ) from (
    select fg2.id from field_gro fg
    join field_gro2 fg2
    on fg2.field_gro_id = fg.id
    where  fg.field_id = f.id GROUP BY fg.id) as foo) as field_gro2_ids 
from fields as f
where
f.id IN (882105, 882104)
```

executing the query I get the error:
**Unknown column 'f.id' in 'where clause'** caused by the nested condition
**fg.field_id = f.id**

is there any workaround to pass the **f.id** reference to the nested query?

**UPDATE:**

i'm sorry but i can't provide more context about the problem

the desired result is:

| field_id | field_gro_count | field_gro_ids |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 882105 | 5 | 123,421,342 |
| 882104 | 5 | 321,453,221 |

Comment: No. Moreover, this is absolutely illogical - you use implicit GROUP BY, hence separate column value makes no sense.

Comment: Post the task itself, not only your attempt to solve.

Comment: thanks for answer @Akina, i'm sorry but I can't share too much, but I'll try to provide more context. the group by is explicit in the complete query, this is just a piece, I add it in the example anyway

Answer (score 0):

error shows that  **you miss the proper reference for f.id**.because mysql doesn't recognized where your f.id column is, so i'm sure you miss the proper reference.

Comment: Hi @Abhay, the same reference is used in other subquery, the problem is only in this one with more then one level of nesting. i update the example with an other working subquery

Comment: here is the problem. select count(*) from field_gro fg where fg.field_id = f.id      you used count for field_gro fg but you done wrong with where condition, mysql doesnt recognized this f.id is not in the same table.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but the select count work fine like other similar subqueries which I have not included for the sake of clarity. the first subquery and the second are independent and do not impact each other, so using the same aliases is not a problem, beyond that, the f alias is unique. As you said, the problem is that mysql doesn't recognize f.id in second subquery, but i think it's caused by the level of nesting, otherwise the other subqueries would not work either. the incriminated where condition must be on that level.